# https without www errors out

Tags: ssl, https, amazon-cloudfront, namecheap

I've registered my domain at Namecheap (example.com), bought ssl from ssls.com, serving content from AWS S3 using AWS CloudFront. Imported the certificate to AWS Certificate Manager. All of the above correctly redirects to https://www.cashflowbux.com :

```
cashflowbux.com
www.cashflowbux.com
http://cashflowbux.com
http://www.cashflowbux.com
```

The issue is when I type https://cashflowbux.com , it throws ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT . Can anyone suggest how to fix it please?

Namecheap replied saying

> If you wish to make it redirect via HTTPS, it is required to point
> your bare/root domain to hosting directly and install an SSL
> certificate there. It is not possible to install it on our BasicDNS
> nameservers.

Comment: Alex, do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2):

In the same way that you had to create a record on your DNS zone "www.cashflowbux.com" record as CNAME type to "d9cmuu1x2w6f7.cloudfront.net", you must create a CNAME "cashflowbux.com" record to "d9cmuu1x2w6f7.cloudfront.net": your DNS provider must supports CNAME records on a root domain using techniques such as CNAME flattening for this.

If is not possible for it, you probably need to migrate your DNS zone to Route53 which supports this feature well.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/rVZDENV.png - I have to provide "host" value. What to set it to in your 2nd suggestion?